Error During App Distribution: Asset Validation Failed Due to Bitcode in Agora Frameworks

I'm facing an issue while distributing my Flutter app to the App Store, which uses the Agora SDK. The distribution process fails with the following asset validation errors, indicating that bitcode is present in several Agora framework files:
Asset validation failed
Invalid Executable. The executable 'Runner.app/Frameworks/AgoraReplayKitExtension.framework/AgoraReplayKitExtension' contains bitcode. (ID: 10f7ca5e-1101-4206-b6c1-d1668fc290a4)
* Asset validation failed
Invalid Executable. The executable 'Runner.app/Frameworks/AgoraRtcKit.framework/AgoraRtcKit' contains bitcode. (ID: 449470b6-da31-4f54-808d-6bcc360f898e)

I tried using a script in my Podfile to strip bitcode from the Agora frameworks, but the errors persist. Here's the relevant part of my Podfile where I attempt to strip bitcode:
bitcode_strip_path = `xcrun --find bitcode_strip`.chop!

def strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
  framework_path = File.join(Dir.pwd, framework_relative_path)
  command = "#{bitcode_strip_path} #{framework_path} -r -o #{framework_path}"
  puts "Stripping bitcode: #{command}"
  system(command)
end

framework_paths = [
  "Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/ReplayKit/Frameworks/AgoraReplayKitExtension.framework/AgoraReplayKitExtension",
  "Pods/AgoraRtcEngine_iOS/RtcBasic/Frameworks/AgoraRtcKit.framework/AgoraRtcKit",
  
]

framework_paths.each do |framework_relative_path|
  strip_bitcode_from_framework(bitcode_strip_path, framework_relative_path)
end

Despite this, I continue receiving the bitcode errors. What could I be missing, and how can I resolve this issue to successfully distribute my app?

Additional Information:

Flutter SDK version: 3.24.0
Xcode version: 16.0
Agora SDK version: agora_rtc_engine: ^5.3.1 I'm using the AgoraRtcEngine_iOS pod for Agora integration in my app.

Podfile.lock:

agora_rtc_engine (5.3.1):
AgoraIrisRTC_iOS (= 3.7.0.3)
AgoraRtcEngine_iOS (= 3.7.0.3)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This helps me
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79086096/showing-error-when-try-to-upload-on-testflight-asset-validation-failed-invalid
