Showing error when try to upload on TestFlight. Asset validation failed Invalid Executable. AgoraRtmKit' contains bitcode
I getting this error indicates that there’s a problem with bitcode in the AgoraRtmKit.framework and FBSDKCoreKit.  I do change to the podfile
refference to this. Also do changes for AgoraRtmKit FBSDKCoreKit but then its not even Build my app.
here is my podfile. Do I've to make any other changes? with this podfile atleast I can archive the build. Also make the ENABLE_BITCODE set to NO in my Xcode
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '16.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Debug-dev' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end

I also tried with this below podfile. I able to archive but still the bitCode error
    # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '16.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.generated_projects.each do |project|
    project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '13.0'
         end
    end
end
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
     if target.name == 'MapboxMobileEvents'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/MapboxMobileEvents/MapboxMobileEvents.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/MapboxMobileEvents -o Pods/MapboxMobileEvents/MapboxMobileEvents.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/MapboxMobileEvents.framework/MapboxMobileEvents`
      end

      if target.name == 'MapboxCommon'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/MapboxCommon/MapboxCommon.xcframework/ios-arm64/MapboxCommon.framework/MapboxCommon -o Pods/MapboxCommon/MapboxCommon.xcframework/ios-arm64/MapboxCommon.framework/MapboxCommon`
      end

      if target.name == 'MapboxCoreMaps'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/MapboxCoreMaps/MapboxCoreMaps.xcframework/ios-arm64/MapboxCoreMaps.framework/MapboxCoreMaps -o Pods/MapboxCoreMaps/MapboxCoreMaps.xcframework/ios-arm64/MapboxCoreMaps.framework/MapboxCoreMaps`
      end

      if target.name == 'AgoraRtmKit'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/AgoraRtmKit/AgoraRtmKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/AgoraRtmKit.framework/AgoraRtmKit -o Pods/AgoraRtmKit/AgoraRtmKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/AgoraRtmKit.framework/AgoraRtmKit`
      end

      if target.name == 'FBAEMKit'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/FBAEMKit/FBAEMKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit -o Pods/FBAEMKit/FBAEMKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit`
      end

      if target.name == 'FBSDKCoreKit'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit -o Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit`
      end

      if target.name == 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics -o Pods/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics`
      end

      if target.name == 'FBSDKLoginKit'
        `xcrun -sdk iphoneos bitcode_strip -r Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit -o Pods/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit`
      end
  end
end


I able to solve this by running all the commends on my terminal for each framework
Here how i get the Framework path(which gives me bitCode Error, your path might be different). Right click and copy the path.

cd ios
cd Pods
Then run: xcrun bitcode_strip -r YourFrameWorkPath
Example ( xcrun bitcode_strip -r AgoraRtm_iOS/AgoraRtmKit.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/AgoraRtmKit.framework/AgoraRtmKit -o AgoraRtm_iOS/AgoraRtmKit.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/AgoraRtmKit.framework/AgoraRtmKit)



Then started running commends for all my freamwork(for me its 5 framework which giving me the error)


BitCode error: need to run this commends in Terminal.

xcrun bitcode_strip -r AgoraRtm_iOS/AgoraRtmKit.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/AgoraRtmKit.framework/AgoraRtmKit -o AgoraRtm_iOS/AgoraRtmKit.xcframework/ios-arm64_armv7/AgoraRtmKit.framework/AgoraRtmKit
xcrun bitcode_strip -r FBSDKLoginKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit -o FBSDKLoginKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKLoginKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKLoginKit.framework/FBSDKLoginKit
xcrun bitcode_strip -r FBSDKCoreKit_Basics/XCFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics -o FBSDKCoreKit_Basics/XCFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics.framework/FBSDKCoreKit_Basics
xcrun bitcode_strip -r FBAEMKit/XCFrameworks/FBAEMKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit -o FBAEMKit/XCFrameworks/FBAEMKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBAEMKit.framework/FBAEMKit
xcrun bitcode_strip -r FBSDKCoreKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit -o FBSDKCoreKit/XCFrameworks/FBSDKCoreKit.xcframework/ios-arm64/FBSDKCoreKit.framework/FBSDKCoreKit

Thank you for sharing! It was really helpful and time saving

Try downgrading your Xcode to 15.x.x version for now, the issue happens on Xcode 16.

No, there's no need to downgrade, as that's not the solution. I've already fixed the issue and provided the answer below in my own question.
