Asset validation failed (contains bitcode) in xcode
When I try to validate ios builds on xcode 15, ios 18, I face this issue. Asset Validation failed, contains bitcode.

This files are in frameworks, but not in Pod file. I didn't add them myself.
I tried to delete podlock or pod file and agains install.
Enable bitcode is NO in build settings

This is the bit code error that is not supported in Xcode 16. I face the same error, and here is the solution. Apple Doc says the same, but it takes me time to understand.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79086096/showing-error-when-try-to-upload-on-testflight-asset-validation-failed-invalid/79269051#79269051:~:text=able%20to%20solve%20this%20by%20running%20all%20the%20commends%20on%20my%20terminal%20for%20each%20framework

SOLUTION: Just update "ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min" to version 6.0.3 in pubspec.yaml. Now it works
